# Corda & React Native compatible?

Tags: react-native, kotlin, corda

Is Corda compatible with React Native?

What is the best way to develop a mobile application with Corda?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that, but you need several moving parts:

- A `Braid` webserver which detects your flows and generates `Open API` compatible templates.
- An `Open API Generator` which translates those templates into an API library (in NodeJS for instance).
- A `React` front-end.

You can find an example implantation of the above approach [here](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/iou-reactfrontend-Braid).
I also wrote an article about `Braid` [here](https://blog.b9lab.com/cordacon-2019-highlights-braid-server-and-openapi-generator-for-corda-flows-api-s-d24179ccb27c).

Answer (score 0):

Corda Node cannot be run on a mobile device. Hence a mobile app and a CorDapp would be separate components.

- You could build your mobile app using react-native.
- The mobile app could connect to a Corda node using REST API exposes by a client.
- The client connects to the node using RPC and relays user inputs to the node.